# Cleaner way of "finding" a range of values

Tags: excel, vba, search

So I currently a macro that assigns a cell value to a variable and then search for this variable on a another sheet.  The problem is that I am having to do this a large number values so I currently have the same code copied 20 times allowing for 20 values to be search in series.  Is there a cleaner method of running a repeatable operation like this?  Also is it possible to set the upper limit based on the number of values entered.  E.g. my current setup looks cells M8:M27 for it's variables, is it possible however to write it so that it is repeated continuously until it hits a blank cell?  Thereby letting the user enter as many values as required?

Here is an extract for a single variable.  This is then repeated up to reverse_id_20

```
Sheets("GR Input").Select
reverse_id_1 = Range("O8")

Sheets("PchOrds").Select

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Find(What:=reverse_id_1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Select
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Sheets("GR Input").Select
```

Thanks in advance guys,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a cleaner method of running a repeatable operation like this?

Yes, it is. You can use loop for it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim reverse_id As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r_id As Variant

    With Sheets("GR Input")
        reverse_id = .Range("O8:O11")
    End With

    For Each r_id In reverse_id
        Set rng = Sheets("PchOrds").Columns("A:A").Find( _
                                    What:=r_id, _
                                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next r_id

End Sub
```

Btw, code above deletes only first row that meet criteria. If you'd like to delete *all* values from sheet "PchOrds", that meet criteria, use this code:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim reverse_id As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim r_id As Variant

    With Sheets("GR Input")
        reverse_id = .Range("O8:O11")
    End With

    For Each r_id In reverse_id
        If r_id <> "" Then
            With Sheets("PchOrds")
                lastrow = Application.Max(2, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
                .AutoFilterMode = False
                With .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & r_id & "*"
                    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(lastrow - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                End With
                .AutoFilterMode = False
            End With
        End If
    Next r_id

End Sub
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks!  Is it possible to use a similar technique on the variables themselves?  Creating enough variables isn't too much trouble, it just creates a bulky code.  Not the end of the world if it can't be done.

Comment: sorry don't understand what do you mean? Are you asking the way to change `reverse_id(1 To 4)` to variables `reverse_id_1`, `reverse_id_2` and so on?

Comment: Using this method I still have to list each variable, this is fine however it's a tad cumbersome when you're dealing with thousands of variables.  Is there anyway to create a range of variables instead of listing each one?

Comment: if your data are in specific range in the sheet, you can use `Dim arr as Variant` and then `arr = Range("O6:O1000")`. Is it what you want? `arr` would contain all values from `O6:O1000` range

Comment: Ah yes that's what I'm looking for.  Not exactly sure how to implement it here though.

Comment: see my new updated answer for general case - when you'd like to delete  _all_ rows, that meet criteria

Comment: Yeah I altered it to that however I'm getting an error on the find section now.

        Set rng = Sheets("PchOrds").Columns("A:A").Find( _
                                    What:=reverse_id(i), _
                                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)

"Subscript out of range"

Comment: "Subscript out of range" with both formats.  The data it is looking up is unique so there should only be one instance of each variable value to delete

Comment: Solution one does the trick spot on now, I can just alter the range size.  Thanks for the help!